# not able to bind image form image source windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone

here is code ..

```
 public class contactsclass
    {
        public Uri imgs;

        public contactsclass()
        {

        }

    }
```

xmal file :-

```
  < ListBox x:Name="listbox1" Margin="0,0" >

  < DataTemplate>

< Image  Name="c1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0" Source="{Binding imgs}"/>

  < /DataTemplate>

< /ListBox>
```

code behind file

```
contactsclass cn = new contactsclass();

cn.imgs= new Uri(("Assets/plus.jpg"),UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

listcontact.Add(cn);


listbox1.ItemsSource = listcontact;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding works with public properties only, not with fields.

Change

```
public Uri imgs;
```

to

```
public Uri imgs { get; set; }
```